# VM error: The constructor should be payable if you send value

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, remix, evm

I have used the Token Contract from https://www.ethereum.org/token#the-code . I have set the buy/sell price as 1000000000000000000 wei, but when i try to buy token from another account by sending 1 ether it return an error!
    [image]

i have used Remix Solidity Ide compiler version:0.4.22+commit.4cb486ee.Emscripten.clang
Environment: Java Script VM

[image: value:1 ether]

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract owned {
address public owner;
constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
    owner = newOwner;
}
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 
_value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }

contract TokenERC20 {
// Public variables of the token
string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals = 0;
uint256 public totalSupply;

// This creates an array with all balances
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 
_value);

// This notifies clients about the amount burnt
event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

/**
 * Constrctor function
 *
 * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the 
contract
 */
constructor(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    string tokenSymbol
) public payable {
    totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total 
supply with the decimal amount
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator 
       all initial tokens
    name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for 
     display purposes
    symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol 
        for display purposes
}

/**
 * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
 */
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal{
    // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require(_to != 0x0);
    // Check if the sender has enough
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    // Check for overflows
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
    // Save this for an assertion in the future
    uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
    // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    // Add the same to the recipient
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. 
 They should never fail
    assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
 *
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) 
{
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens from other address
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
 *
 * @param _from The address of the sender
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public 
 returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 */
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
    returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address and notify
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, 
  and then ping the contract about it
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
 */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
    public
    returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
 *
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has 
enough
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
    totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
    emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens from other account
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
 *
 * @param _from the address of the sender
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool 
 success) {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the 
targeted balance is enough
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the 
 targeted balance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;         // Subtract from the sender's allowance
    totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update 
totalSupply
    emit Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
}
}

 contract MyAdvancedToken is owned, TokenERC20 {

uint256 public sellPrice;
uint256 public buyPrice;

mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

/* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients 
  */
            event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

/* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the 
contract */
constructor(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    string tokenSymbol
) TokenERC20(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public payable {}

/* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    require (_to != 0x0);                               // Prevent transfer 
to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);               // Check if the 
sender has enough
    require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for 
overflows
    require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                     // Check if sender is frozen
    require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                       // Check if recipient is frozen
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
}

/// @notice Create `mintedAmount` tokens and send it to `target`
/// @param target Address to receive the tokens
/// @param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
    balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
    totalSupply += mintedAmount;
    emit Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
    emit Transfer(address(this), target, mintedAmount);
}

/// @notice `freeze? Prevent | Allow` `target` from sending & receiving tokens
/// @param target Address to be frozen
/// @param freeze either to freeze it or not
function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
    frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
    emit FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
}

/// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
/// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
/// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
    sellPrice = newSellPrice;
    buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
}

/// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
function buy() payable public {
    uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;               // calculates the amount
    _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);              // makes the transfers
}

/// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
/// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
function sell(uint256 amount) public {
    address myAddress = this;
    require(myAddress.balance >= amount * sellPrice);      // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
    _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);              // makes the transfers
    msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);          // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
}
}
```

seen several questions of this kind.. but no solution yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine for me once I get it to compile by removing the extra line breaks. (The code in your post has line breaks that cause some comments to no longer be comments.)

Here's what I did in Remix:

1. Deploy with the parameters `1, "test token", "TEST"`. This gives the deploying address possession of 1 token. (Verify with `balanceOf`.)
2. Call `transfer` with the parameters `<address of contract>, 1` to transfer the token to the contract. (Verify with `balanceOf`.)
3. Call `setPrices` with the parameters `0, "1000000000000000000"` to set the `buyPrice` to `1*10^18`. (Verify with `buyPrice`.)
4. Call `buy` and attach 1 ether.
5. Call `balanceOf` with my address as a parameter to verify I now have 1 token.

Comment: do you used same address for deploying and buying??? @smarx

Comment: Why so many question marks??? Yes, I did, but it doesn't matter. (You need to use the same account to do steps 1-3, because only the deploying account has tokens initially, and only the deploying account is allowed to call `setPrices()`. After that, any account can call `buy()`.)

Comment: i have tried with same parameters, but still the error continues

Comment: It's hard to know where things are going wrong without more details. What does `buyPrice()` return right before you buy? What does `balanceOf(<contract address>)` return?

Comment: its okay now :) @smarx

Comment: but why it returns error before?

Comment: Only you know what you did the first time (when you saw the error). I can't tell you what you did.

Comment: i didn't transfer tokens to smart contract address.